# Simple API call to management.azure.com

Tags: c#, json, azure, azure-management-api

I am building a very simple maintenance app for a website hosted on Azure. I want to display a few details such as website online status (on/off), server location, latest deployment(s) and so forth. So rather then browsing the azure portal I want to see a few things on a single page in the maintenance app.

https://resources.azure.com shows off the azure management API I want to use.

The question is how can I get back a JSON object with information displayed above?
A call would be made at the following url: https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/subscription_id/resourceGroups/Default-Web-NorthEurope/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/my-website?api-version=2014-06-01

Apart from the API endpoints, the application above doesn't tell me much.
For example how does the authentication object needed looks like (the one used during a GET/POST)? I am building this in C#.

Answer (score 1):

This helped me so far : 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tomholl/archive/2014/11/25/unattended-authentication-to-azure-management-apis-with-azure-active-directory.aspx.
though I have still having issue on udating it but I'm getting the json data.

Comment: That's exactly what I ended up a using as a starting point. Then I used Json.NET to parse the response.